# Android layout error: no resource identifier found for attribute 'lineWidth' in package

Tags: android, xml

I already import [viewpagerindicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), but when I make the project, the complier show the error.
The error message is :  error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'lineWidth' in package 'com.example.sample'
My use IDE is Intellij.
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        app:lineWidth="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you need to put below  vpi_attrs.xml file in values folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ViewPagerIndicator">
        <!-- Style of the circle indicator. -->
        <attr name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle" format="reference"/>
        <!-- Style of the icon indicator's views. -->
        <attr name="vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle" format="reference"/>
        <!-- Style of the line indicator. -->
        <attr name="vpiLinePageIndicatorStyle" format="reference"/>
        <!-- Style of the title indicator. -->
        <attr name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle" format="reference"/>
        <!-- Style of the tab indicator's tabs. -->
        <attr name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle" format="reference"/>
        <!-- Style of the underline indicator. -->
        <attr name="vpiUnderlinePageIndicatorStyle" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>

    <attr name="centered" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="selectedColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="strokeWidth" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="unselectedColor" format="color" />

    <declare-styleable name="CirclePageIndicator">
        <!-- Whether or not the indicators should be centered. -->
        <attr name="centered" />
        <!-- Color of the filled circle that represents the current page. -->
        <attr name="fillColor" format="color" />
        <!-- Color of the filled circles that represents pages. -->
        <attr name="pageColor" format="color" />
        <!-- Orientation of the indicator. -->
        <attr name="android:orientation"/>
        <!-- Radius of the circles. This is also the spacing between circles. -->
        <attr name="radius" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Whether or not the selected indicator snaps to the circles. -->
        <attr name="snap" format="boolean" />
        <!-- Color of the open circles. -->
        <attr name="strokeColor" format="color" />
        <!-- Width of the stroke used to draw the circles. -->
        <attr name="strokeWidth" />
        <!-- View background -->
        <attr name="android:background"/>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="LinePageIndicator">
        <!-- Whether or not the indicators should be centered. -->
        <attr name="centered" />
        <!-- Color of the unselected lines that represent the pages. -->
        <attr name="unselectedColor" />
        <!-- Color of the selected line that represents the current page. -->
        <attr name="selectedColor" />
        <!-- Width of each indicator line. -->
        <attr name="lineWidth" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Width of each indicator line's stroke. -->
        <attr name="strokeWidth" />
        <!-- Width of the gap between each indicator line. -->
        <attr name="gapWidth" format="dimension" />
        <!-- View background -->
        <attr name="android:background"/>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="TitlePageIndicator">
        <!-- Screen edge padding. -->
        <attr name="clipPadding" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Color of the footer line and indicator. -->
        <attr name="footerColor" format="color" />
        <!-- Height of the footer line. -->
        <attr name="footerLineHeight" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Style of the indicator. Default is triangle. -->
        <attr name="footerIndicatorStyle">
            <enum name="none" value="0" />
            <enum name="triangle" value="1" />
            <enum name="underline" value="2" />
        </attr>
        <!-- Height of the indicator above the footer line. -->
        <attr name="footerIndicatorHeight" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Left and right padding of the underline indicator. -->
        <attr name="footerIndicatorUnderlinePadding" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Padding between the bottom of the title and the footer. -->
        <attr name="footerPadding" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Position of the line. -->
        <attr name="linePosition">
            <enum name="bottom" value="0"/>
            <enum name="top" value="1"/>
        </attr>
        <!-- Color of the selected title. -->
        <attr name="selectedColor" />
        <!-- Whether or not the selected item is displayed as bold. -->
        <attr name="selectedBold" format="boolean" />
        <!-- Color of regular titles. -->
        <attr name="android:textColor" />
        <!-- Size of title text. -->
        <attr name="android:textSize" />
        <!-- Padding between titles when bumping into each other. -->
        <attr name="titlePadding" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Padding between titles and the top of the View. -->
        <attr name="topPadding" format="dimension" />
        <!-- View background -->
        <attr name="android:background"/>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="UnderlinePageIndicator">
        <!-- Whether or not the selected indicator fades. -->
        <attr name="fades" format="boolean" />
        <!-- Length of the delay to fade the indicator. -->
        <attr name="fadeDelay" format="integer" />
        <!-- Length of the indicator fade to transparent. -->
        <attr name="fadeLength" format="integer" />
        <!-- Color of the selected line that represents the current page. -->
        <attr name="selectedColor" />
        <!-- View background -->
        <attr name="android:background"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Hope it will solve your error. Enjoy!!!

Comment: Thank you, I solve the error. But I have other question:In  viewpagerindicator library's values folder has other vip_xxx.xml files, I need add that file in my project's values folder?

Comment: yes. you need to add all vpi__colors,vpi__defaults,vpi__styles file.